# what's this equation with lambda notation " m >> n = m >>= \_ -> n " in monad's declaration?

Tags: haskell, lambda, monads, lambda-calculus

```
class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  (>>)   :: m a -> m b -> m b
  m >> n = m >>= \_ -> n

  fail   :: String -> m a
```

I've never seen a equation(or function declaration?) in typeclass before. Why is there a equation in typeclass?

I know **_** is a term for matching anything. but what **m >>= \_ -> n** match?

Comment: I just realized that **\\_ -> n** throws the first parameter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a default implementation for the method. Unless your instance declaration contains an explicit implementation of `(>>)`, that's the definition that will be used. Default methods are widespread if some method can be implemented using another method, but potentially there can be more efficient implementations for some datatypes.

```
m >>= \_ -> n
```

means the 'result' of `m` is fed to the function that ignores its argument and returns `n` no matter. It could also be written

```
m >>= const n
```

In the context of monads with effects, it's 'do `m` to have the effects, but ignore the return value, then do `n`'. That's what `(>>)` is meant to do there.